# É possível definir a posição do mouse com JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Preciso criar uma extensão para uma aplicação de um amigo que roda em um servidor Node.js (se não me engano, nem manjo muito disso também), quero saber se existe uma forma de definir a posição do mouse com JavaScript ou pelo menos "enganar a aplicação" pra pegar uma falsa posição, é possível fazer isso com JavaScript?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Não, não é possível definir a posição do mouse com JavaScript.

E gostaria de complementar com um trecho traduzido de [uma resposta que encontrei no SO em Inglês](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4752512/1324082):

> Pense nas possíveis implicações que isso poderia ter, se você pudesse ;)
>
> 1. Usuário pensa: "Ei, eu gostaria de clicar nesse link"
> 2. Javascript move o cursor para outro link
> 3. Usuário clica no link errado e inadvertidamente baixa um malware que formata seu disco local C e come todas os seus doces