# Como esse site "manipulou" a posição do mouse?

Tags: javascript, segurança

Como de praxe, [essa questão](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/112087/%C3%89-poss%C3%ADvel-definir-a-posi%C3%A7%C3%A3o-do-mouse-com-javascript) já há uma resposta para isso. Infelizmente me surpreendi ao navegar em um site malicioso sem querer. Ele conseguiu manipular a posição do mouse, impedindo que eu acessasse um elemento na página. Alguém pode entender como ele fez isso? Tentei pegar a codificação acessando as ferramentas de desenvolvedor, mas eles dificultam muito.

Não sei se posso postar o site aqui, por ser perigoso, mas posso editar a pergunta e inserir depois. No momento vou colocar um vídeo do site sobre o qual estou falando:

> www.abner.xyz/video/video.mp4

O link para o site é (cuidado ao acessar):

> app.freerealapp.cool/landing/propwl/688988/?lp=2

Comment: A maior parte dos que eu vi fazendo isso "simula" um cursor que não é o verdadeiro - esconde o original e exibe um "desenho" de flecha. - No caso específico desse mencionado, link app(.)freerealapp(.)cool ,  pode ser algum malware que usa algum bug do chrome (no caso, os muitos bugs do chrome são conhecidos como "features"). Aliás, acho incrivel tanta gente usar esse browser.

Comment: @Bacco! Tem razão! Uma imagem simulando o mouse é exibida e eu não percebi. Assim que eu tento clicar em algum lugar do site aparece o mouse verdadeiro. Se conseguir acessar o link que coloquei na edição da pergunta poderá fazer o teste.

Comment: Eu nao uso chrome, nos outros browsers nao abre. Tenho o chrome em VM de testes pra aferir funcionalidade de trabalhos meus, mas não no PC que estou usando no momento.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A resposta mais plausível de como o site conseguiu fazer esse feito é utilizando  Keyword values, mais precisamente o "none"

> cursor: none;

Dessa forma ele consegue "ocultar" o cursor porém o mesmo continua no local, caso você clique com o botão direito do mouse por exemplo ( seria um excelente teste ) conseguiria identificar o local exato do cursor, logo acima do local exato do seu cursor ele adicionaria uma imagem "fora do alert" de um cursor enganando assim qualquer pessoa que tivesse tentando clicar para sair, porém volto a lembrar que se você clicar mesmo sem ver o cursor daria certo, atualmente nem futuramente creio que seja possível conseguir manipular o cursor do mouse com javascript exceto com uma extensão instalada diretamente no browser ou algo do tipo.

```html
<div style="cursor:none;">Teste cursor</div>
```